# Sum of projection operators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $p_1, ..., p_n$ $n$ projection operators on the vector space $E$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$ is a projection operator.

How to show that $\forall i,j \text{ s.t. } i \neq j, p_i \circ p_j = 0$ ?

I showed this for the case $n=2$ but I can't extend it by induction.

Comment: You work here, I supose, with some inner product, don't you?

Comment: @Joanpemo : I'm not sure what you mean but $\circ$ here is the composition law.

Comment: Yes, I know that, thank you. I was asking because I began thinking of a probable proof using inner product, yet I'm not that sure already.

Comment: @Joanpemo : sorry I'm not familiar with the english vocabulary. No, $E$ is not an inner product space, but only a vector space. Altought, a proof, even assuming $E$ is an inner product space, would be very interesting, and I'd love to see it :)